# How yo fix encoding by python.csv

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have got a programm with making the report by python into csv.
There is a function to do it:

```
def download_report(request, date):
    food_orders = FoodOrder.objects.filter(order__date__date=date)

    response = HttpResponse(
        content_type="text/csv",
        headers={"Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="report.csv"'}
    )

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow([date])

    total_cost_of_all_orders = 0

    for order in food_orders:
        order_time = order.order.date.strftime('%H:%M')
        customer_name = order.order.employee.name
        dishes = '; '.join([str(dish) for dish in order.food.all()])
        order_cost = order.total_cost

        writer.writerow([f'Time: {order_time}, Name: {customer_name}, Food: {dishes}, Cost: {order_cost} rub.'])

        total_cost_of_all_orders += order_cost

    writer.writerow(['', '', '', 'Total cost of day:', total_cost_of_all_orders])

    return response
```

It works good, but when i open my report.csv it get me some incomprehensible symbols:[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), see references to `encoding=..`.   Encoding errors (disagreement) can happen both at reading and writing end, and also when the resulting file is to be used.  You don't give example of input, and you don't give information about desired encoding in output. Write down for yourself : source_encoding ==> output_encoding ==> user_expected_encoding.

Comment: Because it's Django, and i import this function into my views

Comment: Follow up: Your output may in fact be correct, but in in disagreement with whatever reads the output.

Comment: As per your other question (now closed): The string `Р‘Р»СЋРґРѕ,РљРѕР»-РІРѕ,Р¦РµРЅР°,РЎСѓРјРјР°` is EXACTLY what you get when viewing the UTF-8 encoded string `Блюдо,Кол-во,Цена,Сумма` using Cyrillic Windows 1251 encoding. So technically the output is correct the viewer just gets it wrong. Suggest you open report.csv using something else than excel, capable of reading UTF8. Or, tell Excel by data import that it IS utf8. Without the BOM, excel assumes local codepage.

Comment: I had this same problem with CSV files this week... MS Excel 365 let's you save as `CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited`, and it is not obvious this is different that the regular `CSV (Comma delimited)` option (all the options in the Save As box are out of order, it's just a jumble). And reading the first character of the file actually gives you the BOM, which is not expected, and not always there.